# Qt project include file not found

Tags: qt-creator

I have `QtCreator` project named **UePOSCommClient**, which is some **GUI applications**, which is dependent on another `QtCreator` project, named **UePOSCommProtocol**, which is implementation of communications protocol betwwen **UePOSCommClient** and some **Server app**. Here is **UePOSCommClient** projects directory hirerachy:

```
uePOSCommClient/
├── build
│   └── x64
│       ├── debug
│       │   ├── main.o
│       │   ├── Makefile
│       │   ├── moc_uemainwindow.cpp
│       │   ├── moc_uemainwindow.o
│       │   ├── uemainwindow.o
│       │   └── uePOSCommClient
│       └── release
├── main.cpp
├── uemainwindow.cpp
├── uemainwindow.h
├── uePOSCommClient.pro
└── uePOSCommClient.pro.user
```

and here is **UePOSCommProtocol**'s project's directoty hirerachy:

```
uePOSCommProtocol/
├── build
│   └── x64
│       ├── debug
│       │   ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│       │   ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1 -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│       │   ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0 -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│       │   ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│       │   ├── Makefile
│       │   ├── moc_uemessageheader.cpp
│       │   ├── moc_uemessageheader.o
│       │   ├── moc_uemessagerequest.cpp
│       │   ├── moc_uemessagerequest.o
│       │   ├── moc_ueposcommprotocol.cpp
│       │   ├── moc_ueposcommprotocol.o
│       │   ├── uemessageheader.o
│       │   ├── uemessagerequest.o
│       │   └── ueposcommprotocol.o
│       └── release
│           ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│           ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1 -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│           ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0 -> libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│           ├── libuePOSCommProtocol.so.1.0.0
│           ├── Makefile
│           ├── moc_uemessageheader.cpp
│           ├── moc_uemessageheader.o
│           ├── moc_uemessagerequest.cpp
│           ├── moc_uemessagerequest.o
│           ├── moc_ueposcommprotocol.cpp
│           ├── moc_ueposcommprotocol.o
│           ├── uemessageheader.o
│           ├── uemessagerequest.o
│           └── ueposcommprotocol.o
├── net
│   └── comm_protocol
│       ├── uemessageheader.cpp
│       ├── uemessageheader.h
│       ├── uemessagerequest.cpp
│       ├── uemessagerequest.h
│       └── ueprotocolcommands.h
├── settings
│   └── uedefaults.h
├── ueposcommprotocol.cpp
├── ueposcommprotocol_global.h
├── ueposcommprotocol.h
├── uePOSCommProtocol.pro
└── uePOSCommProtocol.pro.user
```

Now, all works fine, the project **UePOSCommClient** compiles without errors, and runs without problems. However, in **UePOSCommProtocol** project, I have following `#include` statement:

```
#include "../../../../../../../../../home/users/Projects/uePOSCommProtocol/settings/uedefaults.h"
```

which is absolute path to `uedefaults.h` file. I am aware **this is a bad practice** and therefore I've replaced upper `#include` with:

```
#include "settings/uedefaults.h"
```

After doing so now I get `No such file or directory` error:

```
In file included from ../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/ueposcommprotocol.h:7:0,
                 from ../../../uemainwindow.h:11,
                 from ../../../main.cpp:3:
../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/net/comm_protocol/uemessagerequest.h:9:33: fatal error: settings/uedefaults.h: No such file or directory
 #include "settings/uedefaults.h"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
14:43:03: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project uePOSCommClient (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Both projects reside in `/home/user/Projects` directory and why am I getting this error?

P.S.: I am using `Qt 5.6.0 for Linux (64bit)` with `QtCreator 3.6.1` on `Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS (64bit)`.